# in Win2d how to copyPixelsFromBitmap() to another canvasBitmap from specified region in CanvasDrawingSession?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

What i Have Tried is?

```
        IRandomAccessStream random = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//img.jpg")).OpenReadAsync();
        BitmapTransform bitmapTransform = new BitmapTransform();
        bitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 250;
        bitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 500;
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
        PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            bitmapTransform,
            ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
            ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage
            );
        byte[] PixelData = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();
        CanvasBitmap cb = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(sender, PixelData, 500, 250, Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8X8UIntNormalized);

        CanvasBitmap cb1 = null;
        cb.CopyPixelsFromBitmap(cb1, 0,0,100,100,(int)cb.GetBounds(sender).Width,(int) cb.GetBounds(sender).Height);
```

But copyPixelsFromBitmap() method throws an error like this...

[image]

I don't Know How to solve this.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello, you set `cb1` to null, then it does not have any pixels itself, `CopyPixelsFromBitmap` should report parameter errors. Do you want to copy pictures?

Comment: yeah....I Want to copy specified Region pixels of cb to cb1.How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To meet your needs, we recommend `CanvasRenderTarget`. It is a derived class of `CanvasBitmap` and can create new instance.

```cs
async Task<CanvasBitmap> GetImage(CanvasControl sender)
{
    IRandomAccessStream random = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//img.jpg")).OpenReadAsync();
    BitmapTransform bitmapTransform = new BitmapTransform();
    bitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 250;
    bitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 500;
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
    PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        bitmapTransform,
        ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
        ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage
        );
    byte[] PixelData = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();
    CanvasBitmap cb = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(sender, PixelData, 500, 250, DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized);
    var target = new CanvasRenderTarget(sender, 100, 100, img.Dpi,DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,CanvasAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
    target.CopyPixelsFromBitmap(cb, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100);
    return target;
}
```

Simply put, it will be offset by a distance of 100hx100w, creating a 100x100 pixel size area on the basis of cb to display the captured image pixels.

It should be noted that the creation of `CanvasRenderTarget` needs to maintain the same pixel format as the loaded `CanvasBitmap`. In your original question, the pixel type used was `B8G8R8X8UIntNormalized`, it is recommended to change to `B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized`, because the former is not supported in `CanvasRenderTarget`.